# Change position Messages of chat in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I created a custom adapter for my chat page that it show messages in a `listView` for the `firstUser` open a box in right side for show message and for `secondUser` open a box in left side for show message but when full the page and `scroll` the page . change the position of messages ?? 
My code is huge but it is my `Custom Adapter` :

```
public class AdapterConversation extends ArrayAdapter<StructConversation>{
    public static String co;
    public AdapterConversation(ArrayList<StructConversation> array){
        super(G.context, MClear().equals("pasokh") ? R.layout.out : R.layout.in_out_conversation , array);
        MClear();
    }
    private static class ViewHolder{
        public TextView NameTitle;
        public TextView Conver;
        public TextView dateTime;

        public ViewHolder(View view){
            NameTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.NameTitle);
            Conver = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Conver);
            dateTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateTime);
        }
        public void fill(ArrayAdapter<StructConversation> adapter,final StructConversation item, int position){
            NameTitle.setText(item.NameTitle);
            Conver.setText(item.Coversations);
            dateTime.setText(item.dateTime);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        StructConversation item = getItem(position);
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = G.inflater.inflate(MClear().equals("pasokh") ? R.layout.out : R.layout.in_out_conversation, parent,false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.fill(this, item, position);
        return convertView;
    }

    public static String MClear() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = G.context.getSharedPreferences("CONVER", 0);
        co = (sharedPrefs.getString("PSA", "not"));
        sharedPrefs.edit().remove("PSA").commit();
        return co;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't understand your purpose, What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your viewHolder should look just like this:

```
private static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView NameTitle;
    public TextView Conver;
    public TextView dateTime;
}
```

set the members only once when creating the holder

```
if(convertView == null){
        convertView = G.inflater.inflate(MClear().equals("pasokh") ? R.layout.out : R.layout.in_out_conversation, parent,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        // Use findViewById HERE!!
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
```

Comment: Please explain :// Use findViewById HERE!!

Comment: the viewHolder pattern is not mandatory, it is used when you want to avoid using findViewById() too frecuently because it has slow performance. The viewHolder pattern is used to get a smooth list view scrolling. But it make no sense to use this pattern and use findViewById inside it !! Move your code below to use findViewById just once during initialization of the viewHolder. Leave your view holder clean with no methods at all.